# Inherit intellisense for dictionary-like class

Tags: python, dictionary, intellisense, spyder

I have a class **A** for which I have defined `__getitem__`. Is there any way I can get intellisense to autocomplete when getting items from their keys?

I have tried making every "value" of my "dictionary" an attribute of my class. But I am wondering if there are other/easier ways to achieve this.

---

I am using Python (3.6.1) in Spyder (3.1.4).